# Is there a way to open files in a zip file without decompressing (c#)

Tags: c#, zip, compression

my problem is simple, I have a zip file that contains a lot of files (mixed: pdf png and txt). I need to write a C# program that peeks into the zip file, loops through and opens only the png files without decompressing. All the solutions that I find include decompressing the whole zip file which makes the target folder only heavier.
What is the easiest way to do it?

thank you very much,

Josh.

Comment: You probably mean "without decompressing to the file system", or? Decopressing to memory would be OK? Then use [ZipArchiveEntry.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open)

Comment: Here is example from msdn using System.IO.Compression https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry?view=net-5.0 traversing zipEntries and unzipping only specific

Comment: I don't care about memory, I have enough of it! yes I mean without decompressing to the target path like a normal unzipping in windows... sorry if I was not more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe you can use the System.IO.Compression library...

Assembly:  System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll

something like the following...

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            entry.ExtractToFile(destinationPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very good, however I want to open the files and not store them. I used the entry.Open() method . However, nothing opens, i verified with a counter variable that i get the exact number of files inside the zip file which seems to work, the algorithm finds the exact number of png files inside the zipfile

Comment: I did nothing more than replacing the last line with entry.Open()

Comment: Open opens a stream for reading the content. That's probably not what you want. There is no opening a file from an archive in another application without extracting it. You can extract to at temporary file if need be.

Comment: ok I get it now. so I guess I can extract them, open them then delete the temporary folder. thank you everbody for the useful answers